# Update onedrive token programmatically rclone.js config

Tags: javascript, rclone

I'm using the rclone wrapper rclone.js to use rclone inside my nuxt3 app.
It's working well but so far the only way I found to make it work is to update manually the ondrive token inside the config file.

which look like this in /Users/me/.config/rclone/rclone.conf

```
[onedrive]
type = onedrive
client_id = xxxxxxxxx
client_secret = xxxxxxxx
drive_type = business
drive_id = xxxxxxxx
access_scopes = Files.Read Files.Read.All Sites.Read.All offline_access
link_scope = organization
token = {"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"ext_expires_in":3599,"access_token":"xxxxxxxxxx"}
```

I don't see any doc on how to update this token programmatically.

Here is my code that sync my files, for reference:

```
// Import promises from default rclonePkg
import rclonePkg from 'rclone.js'
const { promises: rclonePromises } = rclonePkg

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
    const { onedriveFolder } = await readBody(event)

    const output = await rclonePromises.sync(`onedrive:${onedriveFolder}`, `cloudflare:${process.env.CLOUDFLARE_BUCKET}`, {
      env: {
        RCLONE_CONFIG: process.env.RCLONE_CONFIG
      }
    })

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: `Sync completed successfully!`
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
})
```

I know how to get the token from onedrive but I don't know how to update rclone config

Any idea?